# Saving a text file to android, with adding a new line

Tags: android, text, xamarin

I have a text file, and when the user presses a button it has to add a new line to that text file. I thought this was an easy task, maybe a \n and I'm done. Well, nope.

Here's what I tried:

**First with a streamwriter**

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
{
    sw.WriteLine(familiesSpinner.SelectedItem.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

This didn't work, it didn't add a newline to the end of it. I tried putting System.Environment.NewLine to the before familiesSpinner but that failed the same way.

---

**Then with File.AppendAllText**

```
File.AppendAllText(filename, familiesSpinner.SelectedItem.ToString()  + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Same result, tried putting the NewLine before and after the familiesSpinner, same result.

---

I tried it with \n, \r\n, and &#10 instead of .NewLine, but that didn't work either.

(I am using Xamarin for Visual Studio, and this is an android app.)

Comment: how are you checking the file for newlines?  There are many similar questions on SO about Android newlines, some of them suggest the newlines are getting stripped out when the file is read, not written

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting

```
newStringVariable = miliesSpinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

to a variable separately and then

```
File.AppendAllText(newStringVariable  + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Does that work?

Comment: I got the same result, one long-ass line, ignored the .NewLine here again.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var logStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(logStream))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine("Hello World");
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();

    logStream.Close();
}
```

This peace of code worked for me on Android.

Comment: Same result again, tried exactly the code you wrote, and again with "Hello World\n" and "HelloWorld" + System.Environment.NewLine, but all I got was HelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorld. Thanks for the input though.